# C++ why does my compiler succeed but my computer gives a debug error?

Tags: c++

So I finished addressing the compiler's errors when attempting to run my program, and now from what I see, it succeeds with the compiler, but the console is blank other than the file location and an error window pops up that says "Debug error! [program file location name] abort() has been called" from Microsoft Visual c++ runtime library. I have no clue if this error is caused by my computer or code or what. As you can tell, I am very new to this and haven't the slightest clue how to diagnose a problem not given by the compiler.

Below is the program that gets this error. Designed to eventually perform operations between two values inputted as roman numerals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int conNtoD(char val)
{
    int number;
    if (val == 'M')
    {
        number = 1000;
    }
    else if (val == 'D')
    {
        number = 500;
    }
    else if (val == 'C')
    {
        number = 100;
    }
    else if (val == 'L')
    {
        number = 50;
    }
    else if (val == 'X')
    {
        number = 10;
    }
    else if (val == 'V')
    {
        number = 5;
    }
    else if (val == 'I')
    {
        number = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        number = 0;
    }




    return number;
}

int get_data(string numerone)
{
    int pos = 0;
    char val;
       int totalval1=0;
       int cou = numerone.length();


    while (pos <= cou)
    {
        int number=0;
        val= numerone.at(pos);
        number = conNtoD(val);
        totalval1 = totalval1 + number;


      pos++;


    }




    return totalval1;

}

int get_data2 (string numertwo)
{
    int pos = 0;
    char val;

    int totalval2=0;
    int cou = numertwo.length();

    while (pos <= cou)
    {
        int number = 0;
        val = numertwo.at(pos);
        number = conNtoD(val);

        totalval2 = totalval2 + number;
        pos++;


    }




    return totalval2;
}






int main()
{ 
    string numerone;
    string numertwo;
    char op;
    int x = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    int pos2 = 0;
    ifstream numerals("Numerals.txt");
    while (numerals >> numerone >> numertwo >> op)
    { 

        int totalval1= get_data(numerone);
        int totalval2= get_data2(numertwo);


        cout << numerone << " " << numertwo << " " << op << endl;

        cout << totalval1 << " and " << totalval2 << endl;

    } 



}
```

Comment: *As you can tell, I am very new to this and haven't the slightest clue how to diagnose a problem not given by the compiler.* -- Compiling a program successfully only means there are no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether your program contains logical bugs.  If you wrote a program to add two numbers, and instead you subtracted two numbers, that program would compile without error, but is the program correct?  No.  Use the debugger that comes with your compiler to determine where you are making these logical errors.

Comment: `<=` is not the appropriate comparison with the string length. `<` is.

Comment: It looks like you have two identical functions, except for the naming. The point of functions is to define them once and then pass different values to them.

Comment: `while (pos <= cou) { ... val= numerone.at(pos); } `. This will definitely fail when `pos == cou`

Answer (score 2):

This is your bug

```
    int cou = numerone.length();
    ...
    while (pos <= cou)
```

`cou` is the length of the string.  For example, if your string is "MM", the length is 2.  The valid indices of a string's characters range from 0 up to and including `length-1`.  That is, 0 and 1 are the valid indices for the characters of a string of length 2.

However, your while loop is evaluating `pos` from 0 up to and including the length.  The `at` method will throw an exception when you try to access position 2 for the string `MM`.

The simple fix is to iterate one less

```
    while (pos < cou)
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: Yup. That fixed it. Thank you so much, and I actually recalled knowing your explanation as I thought about it. I just didn't think, given the error I was given that it was as simple as that.

Comment: Well, `length` is a valid index… for a different set of string-methods.

Comment: @Deduplicator - adjusted wording.